# specify comparator function in python dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass in a custom equality comparison function when creating a python dictionary so that it doesn't use the default `__eq__` or `hash` comparators? I'm hoping there is a way to do so but wasn't able to find it so far.

edit: I am looking for a way to provide different definitions of object equality for classes that I defined. Like:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a 
    self.b = b

def c1(a1, a2):  # assume both are A objects
  return a1.a == a2.a

def c2(a1, a2):
  return a1.b == a2.b

# is this possible?
d1 = dict(cmp=c1)  
d2 = dict(cmp=c2)
```

I know I can override `__eq__` etc in my class definition but I can only override it once. In Java I can use [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and I am looking for the equivalent in Python.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo code to clarify what you want to achieve? When do you need that custom comparison function?

Comment: see above edit.

Comment: So you want to add instances of class `A` to your dictionary as a key and when the `dict` wants to check if a key already exists or not you want it to use it your function. Am I correct?

Comment: Not possible, `dict`s defer entirely to the keys' own comparison behavior.  It wouldn't even be possible to implement this using only a comparator function, two keys would have to generate the same hash code before a direct comparison between them would ever be attempted.

Comment: @jasonharper not possible to implement with class `A`/`c1`/`c2`, but you could subclass `dict`/`UserDict`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: you can wrap the key into a new class, of which you can override `__eq__` again.